# accessing re-structured array values in html gives error invalid key attribute

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am bringing in data from apex method call and re-writing the structure of the array in Javascript. I am having trouble accessing array values with the newly created structure.
Below is the HTML:

```
<template for:each={addresses} for:item="address">
   <div class="address-row-container" key={address.key} >
         <div class="address-style"><strong>{address.streetAddress}</strong></div>
   </div>
</template>
```

Here is the JS with newly structured array:

```
@track addresses=[];
this.addresses.push({"streetAddress": result[i].sumchans__Full_Address_Ext_Id__c});
```

[image]

please help. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, you don't have a key specified. Make sure you set one:

```
this.addresses.push({key: result[i].Id, streetAddress: result[i].sumchans__Full_Address_Ext_Id__c});
```

Note that it is idiomatic to use "map" in these types of situations:

```
this.addresses = result.map(record => ({ key: record.Id, streetAddress: record.sumchans__Full_Address_Ext_Id__c}));
```

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, not sure why I didn't get this, after looking at it all day today.